# Progress bar or seek bar like WP7 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, progress-bar

I want to make "progress bar" or seekbar which is in Windows Phone 7 when you are playing video. It´s progress bar with circle in position where you are in movie progress.

First example what I found:
[image: Image showing seekbar in WP7]

I started like this:

```
    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleProgressBase}" x:Key="styleEllipse">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Ellipse Name="PART_Track" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <VisualBrush>
                                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    <Border Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />

                                    </Border>

                                </VisualBrush.Visual>
                            </VisualBrush>

                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I don´t know how to make round corners in this and mainly I don´t know how to add circle.

Edit: And little question to future improvement. Would be hard to implement seeking, browsing in video by touching and moving with that circle?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to open the video directly in media player

Comment: Nope, I am creating application which needs own media player and I like that bar.